# How do you repeat an animation in a swift class

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to take my animating function and turn it into its own class.

Can someone help me figure out how to add repeat functionallity? Ive been trying for two days with no luck.

```
class FlipAnimator {
class func animate(view: UIView) {

    let view = view
    view.layer.transform = FlipAnimatorStartTransform
    view.layer.opacity = 0.8
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
        view.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        view.layer.opacity = 1

    }
}
```

Comment: Did the answer below solve your problem? If not, what other problems are you having?

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. Am I supposed to mark your answer as the answer somehow? I am trying to learn how this site works. Please see my comment below for my other inquiry.

Comment: I've commented a reply to that. If you feel my answer adequately answers your original question, click the checkmark underneath the vote count next to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the available signatures for `animateWithDuration` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:). Note that one of them is `animateWithDuration(_:delay:options:animations:completion:)`. Try using `.Repeat` as the `options` parameter (a full list of options can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewAnimationOptions)).

Specifically:

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: .Repeat, {
        view.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        view.layer.opacity = 1
    }, nil)
```

Note that because `animations` is not the last parameter you cannot use the trailing closure
 syntax.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works! I tried so many variations of this with no luck.

Do you know where I could learn more about setting up animation classes in swift?

More specifically, I am trying to flip two views, have them flip quickly at first, then slow down and stop.

I have searched so much, and have not found anything that looks like how you have it set up here, with the nil part at the end.

Thanks again
Ben

Comment: There is the Apple-produced animation guide at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html. It's not designed for swift, but the principles (and most of the methods) are the same, and Objective-C and swift have enough in common (and share almost all of the methods) that a guide for one is easily applicable to the other.

Comment: Also, Do you know how I go about adding another regular comment? These small comment windows do not let me do much. Do I press the "Answer Your Question" button again?

Comment: Thanks for the link to the animation programming guide. I see this will answer a lot of questions I have.

Comment: If you have a separate question, by all means make another question for it. If you want to edit the original question, do that instead. You can comment on this answer or the original question.